# Vue.js add attribute from mixin

Tags: vuejs2

I'm working on a rather complex and big project. Our QA team decided they want unique id's to do automated testing. Since our developers are rather lazy (we are developers, you know?), we are trying to inject these id's automatically.

I've tried to create a mixin that tries to add an attribute on mounted.

```
mounted() {
  this.$el.setAttribute('data-test-id', 'a-random-id-01');
}
```

But this fails all the time because $el is not always available right away. Does anyone have any insight how we could do this?

Answer (score 0):

Find your question from google :)

```js
this.$el.dataset.testId = 'a-random-id-01'
```